# WebView Android Studio dando erro para abrir links de e-mail mailto:

Tags: java, android, webview

Eu criei um aplicativo utilizando o `WebView` no Android Studio.

Em meu site no qual o `WebView` abre tem links de e-mail que ao clicar deveriam abrir o aplicativo de email padrão do celular. Só que isso não acontece e dá uma mensagem de erro:

> Pagina da web não disponível mailto:endereço de email net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

Código fonte do `WebView`:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private WebView miWebview;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        miWebview = findViewById(R.id.wv_main);
        miWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        miWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        miWebview.loadUrl("http://cariocaempregos.com.br");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ocorre que o webview está fazendo uma requisição interna, para abrir o e-mail. Inclua o código abaixo:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    miWebview = findViewById(R.id.wv_main);
    miWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    miWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    miWebview.loadUrl("http://cariocaempregos.com.br");
    miWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
                return false;
            }

            // Otherwise allow the OS to handle it
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
 }
```

Outro ponto, inclua a tag no `Manifest.xml`:

```
<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ....>
```